# Abstract Class extending Windows.Forms.Form Causing Problems in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm running into a bit of a problem in a VB.Net project I'm currently developing.

I have a bunch of different Forms that I'm using in my project, and they all have some common properties.

I thought I'd make them all inherit from a common abstract class, "LinkableForm", which inherited from Windows.Forms.Form.

My code is running just as it did before I made the abstract class, but I can't use the form designer anymore, because it is inheriting from "LinkableForm" instead of from "Windows.Forms.Form".

My abstract class is simply

```
Public MustInherit Class LinkableForm
    Inherits Windows.Forms.Form

    Public foo As Object

    Public Overridable Sub foo()
    End Sub

End Class
```

And I just changed all my forms from

```
Public Class frmFoo

    [code here]

End Class
```

to

```
Public Class frmFoo
    Inherits LinkableForm

    [code here]

End Class
```

It looks like Visual Studio is not recognizing that this abstract class is simply extending Forms, and so I can't see my forms in the designer. I really don't want to have to code all the UI by hand.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get the designer back without having to significantly change the design of the code? I'd be copying and pasting hundreds of lines of code if I don't contain my forms in an abstract class.

Comment: what is the nature of the stuff you added? Subs and Functions or UI elements?

Comment: I just added two properties (public form objects) and one sub. No functions or elements in the abstract class.

Comment: consider putting that stuff in a class which the forms implement - it is easier.  The IDE needs to compile the form in order to show it in the IUI designer. You can create templates and/or a ClassLib for the new base class so that the IDE can use them.  I find it terribly inconvenient and easier to implement via a custom class, User Controls etc.